# Ruby On Rails 3 submit form AJAX update results in div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am stuck; I did a search and I can't find a pointer on how to get this project to work. I have a form on my index.html.erb as:

```
<html>   <head>
    <title>Ajax List Demo</title>   <h1>Listing posts</h1> 

    <%= javascript_include_tag "prototype" %>   </head>   <body>
    <h3>Add to list using Ajax</h3>
    <% form_tag (  :remote=>true, :update => 'my_list', :action => :list , :method=>:post, :format =>:xml ) do %>

      Enter the url:
      <%= text_field_tag 'url' ,'', :size => 80 %>
      <%= submit_tag "Find" %>
    <% end %>
    <div id="my_list"><%= render :partial => 'profiles/list' %></div>   </body> </html>
```

Now I have a div with this called my_list. When I submit the form I want my partial _list.html.erb (inside profiles dir, tried home dir too) to update with the results of list.

My home controller has this method:

```
def list
    puts "here!!!!"
   reader = Reader.new
  @profiles =  reader.processURL(params[:url])
    render :partial=>'profiles/list', :locals => { :profiles => @profiles}
end
```

I end up getting this error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing partial profiles/list with {:locale=>[:en, :en], :handlers=>[:rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml, :
erb], :formats=>[:xml]} in view paths "C:/Users/....tree/app/views"):
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:22:in `list'

Rendered C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.erb
within rescues/layout (1.0ms)
```

Could anyone help me or send me in the right direction to understand how to update a div rendering via Rails on form submit?  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am getting ajax to `render(@homepages)` in `index.html.erb` via `index.js.erb` OK, but my search to update @homepages is not working.

In your `javascript_include_tag` you missed out `rails.js` which I think handles the ajax request. `javascript_include_tag :defaults` would have done all that for you plus some others that you do not need. Providing you are not using jquery you need prototype and `rails.js` as a minimum.

I do not think the format of this `form_tag` is correct:

```
<% form_tag (:remote=>true, :update => 'my_list', :action => :list , :method=>:post, :format =>:xml) do %>
```

The first value after the "(" should be the `item_path`, then the conditions `:action => :list`.

`:method => post` should take you to the `create` or `new` action.

`:update => 'my_list'` would be done in the `list.js.erb` using javascript (prototype)

The code for jquery and prototype is similar, but slightly different (see [Railscast 205](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript))

Why format xml in the form_tag, put it in the controller "list" mine is:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @homepages }
  format.js
end
```

Don't sure if you can get away with 'url' should not it be :url you might be able to use either.

When I was getting the missing template it was because it was looking for a `search.html.erb` file. In your case it is looking for a `list.html.erb`.